# A question about a notation used in the Folland Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functions, notation

[image]

This is the exercise 11 in the Folland Real Analysis. Could anyone tell me what it means by f(x,・) and f(・,y)? I have never seen such notations before...

Comment: $f(x,\cdot)$ is the *name* of the function $y\mapsto f(x,y)$. It is meant to resemble what happens with $f$ being the *name* of the function $x\mapsto f(x)$, in which the name is formed by making $(x)$ disappear. The $\cdot$ is left to indicate that something did disappear and to tell where was what disappeared.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505166/using-cdot-as-variable-placeholder)